# Im thinking of making a webapp with django, that's basically a wallpaper generator, but where to store and how to display an image on heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, web-deployment

Basically ill be using pillow to create random wallpapers, but ive never worked with images in django, so idk how am i supposed to display the generated image....because whilst hosting on heroku? i know that people store images on AWS and stuff, but how im supposed to do store an image generated from pillow to aws, automatically, or can u even do that?

ps; im not demanding for any code, i just need to get an idea, a kind of a road map or maybe a tutorial if u may.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea:

Start with something simple, like an sqlite3 database on localhost, (no AWS needed), get pillow to store the image within a particular specified directory, and store the relative directory path to the image on sqlite3, such that a variable can be assigned such (a string that contains) the path to the file and be injected into the src component of an img tag. As such:

`<img src="{{ variable_name }}" >`

actually on the subject of randomness this might be a better way to display images using JINJA templating:

`<img src="{{ directory_path }}/{{ random_image_number }} ">`

From here it's matter of just manipulating the variable to randomly pick different files from where the all images are stored. Now if you want to deploy this you may need to use something like PostgreSQL, or some kind of image storing api, like cloudinary, because deployment platforms like Heroku and AWS remove volatile storage files when not in use after 24 hours.

Although this [resource](https://youtu.be/803Ei2Sq-Zs) I'm linking is for Flask, it does cover how to use pillow, with Python's os module to store and display images in JINJA templating using sqlite3, and then the project is eventually deployed using PostgreSQL.